# How to run commands through PTY?

Tags: c

I want to interact with the child process through PTY, the parent process code is as follows:

```c
#include <pty.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t child_pid, current_pid;
    char name[BUFSIZ], buffer[BUFSIZ];
    int master;

    current_pid = getpid();
    fprintf(stdout, "pid: %u\n", current_pid);

    child_pid = forkpty(&master, &name[0], NULL, NULL);
    if (child_pid == -1) {
        perror("forkpty faild.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else if (child_pid == 0) {
        execl("./child", "./child");
    } else {
        read(master, &buffer[0], BUFSIZ);
        fprintf(stdout, "%u: child message:\n%s", current_pid, buffer);
    }

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The subprocess code is as follows:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", isatty(fileno(stdout)) ? "true": "false");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

compile and execute:

```bash
$ gcc main.c -o main && gcc child.c -o child
$ ./main
```

Why must the parent process fork first, and then execute the instruction through execl to be effective?

Can't exchange data directly?

Answer (score 2):

> Why must the parent process fork first, and then execute the instruction through execl to be effective?

Because that's how `fork` and everything that wraps it up works. After a successful `fork` you have two processes that are virtually identical, except for the return value of `fork` and the process' PID.

To launch a different program, one process must replace its program image with a different one, which is what `execl` does.